# vue3 `component.{dollar}options.components`

Tags: vuejs3, vue-component

I'm migrating from Vue2 to Vue3 and I use component.$options.components trying to find the components of parent component, but is undefined.
How can i do it in Vue 3?

`const components = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.xRootComponent.$options.components);`

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do will likely require a different strategy.  Use of composables, provide/inject, store, event bus, etc...  All these things can send/receive data across components.  As of now, you've given an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). _Explain your need_ for the components of parent component. That will help others provide possible solutions.